# Trying to make a simple update but SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I'm trying to make a simple update using two tables but I got this error : SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
I've found a lot solution for that, I've tried them but It still doesn't work ...
Can you please help me to resolve it ?

```
update (SELECT t1.STATUS from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on(t1.ID = t2.ID) 
where t1.STATUS like 'COMPLETE' and t2.PARTY is null) vp set vp.STATUS= 'NEW';
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: For your update to make sense, column `id` in table `table2` shouldn't allow duplicates; it must be constrained as `unique`. Moreover, Oracle requires that this should be known to the parser in advance (meaning: the column must have a unique or a primary key constraint, or a unique index on it). If `id` is supposed to be the primary key in `table2`, is it declared as such? If not, why not?

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, unfortunately I cannot touch the tables in the DB, I don't have the permission to do it. T1.id is the primary key and T2.id is the foreignkey which references T1.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update` but with a correlated subquery:

```
update table1 t1
    set status = 'NEW'
    where t1.status = 'COMPLETE' and
          exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2 
                  where t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.party is null
                 );
```

I suspect that you might also want a condition if there are no rows at all in `table2` but that logic would not conform to your current query.

Comment: Thank you I've used that update and it works well, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO table1 tgt
  USING (SELECT id
         FROM   table2
         WHERE  party IS NULL) src
    ON (tgt.id = src.id) -- ensure this join condition means there's only one source row per target row
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE tgt.status = 'NEW'
  WHERE  tgt.status = 'COMPLETE';
```

Comment: I've never learnt and used the merge statement, I need to check how it works